# Converting old .UFO (Ulead File for Objects) files into JPG or PSD?

Tags: conversion, images

Many years ago I used to use Ulead PhotoImpact on Windows, but have since converted to using Photoshop on a Mac. I've come across some old .UFO files and I'd like to convert them either to flat JPGs or PSDs. I believe Ulead was bought by Corel and PhotoImpact is now not available.

Would anyone happen to know how I could convert the files?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Since it is a proprietary format, you would need to use PI to convert it, there are old copies of PI v 10,11,12 floating around if you know where to look. I still use version 12, it works fine on Windows 7 with the patch they released for Vista.

Comment: Some of Corel's software can be downloaded on a fully functional trial basis including paintshop photo pro. It may be worth while checking to see if your ufo file format is supported in the trial packages.

Answer (score 1):

[They still sell PhotoImpact X3](http://www.corel.com/corel/product/index.jsp?pid=prod3430246&cid=catalog20038&segid=1258&storeKey=us&languageCode=en), which is what I still use for image editing on Windows 7 and 8 (it still works right out of the box!). Once you have that, it can save as JPG or PSD, as well as dozens of other formats.

Comment: Oh great, I had no idea they still sold it! I'll check it out, thanks!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.

Comment: @MichaelWaterfall if this helped you, you might want to accept this as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

**Need to Open a UFO File?** Download PaintShop Pro.
https://www.paintshoppro.com/en/pages/ufo-file
Now open a UFO file then 'save as' any format that retains layers (i.e. png).

Comment: Why are you answering a 11 year old question?

Answer (score 0):

I am the creator of [www.Photopea.com](http://www.Photopea.com) (photo editor in a web browser), and I have implemented this feature yesterday!

You can open your UFO files in Photopea, see layers with their names, etc, and export it as a PSD file (File - Save as PSD).

I don't know if it could help 10, 100 or 1000 people, but I had fun figuring out the meaing of each 0 and 1 inside these strange UFO files :D